# How to get the length of svg text in Elm

Tags: html, svg, elm

Is there any way to get the length of a piece of Svg text in Elm?  I construct text with the [text_](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/svg/2.0.0/Svg#text_) function, but need to know its size so I can position other elements.

The sort of function I am looking for would be something like

```
getLength : Svg.Svg msg -> Int
```

Comment: By "length" you mean the number of characters in the string or the number of pixels the text node occupies on the screen (or something else)?

Comment: I think I mean pixels, if that is the unit of measurement for, say, making a rectangle of a certain width and height, or positioning an element by its x and y coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to get a function as you wish because it could't be pure - it would need to return different values depending on the pixel density.

There's also not a version using Tasks as far as I know, and you can't readily get the size of html elements either. You probably need to use a port to get some javascript to do that for you

Comment: When you say pixel density do you mean that it would depend on the properties of the screen that the user happened to have?  I'm puzzled by this because what I would like is the bounding box of the text in terms of the units of the x, y coordinates that the objects are placed with. Surely this could be determined in a pure way without knowledge of the user's computer / setup?  Or perhaps not because the exact font is not known in advance.

Comment: Yes. But perhaps you could insert your text within a box of fixed proportions